# Create instance of iOS class that contains a . with frida

Tags: ios, frida, hooking

I am trying to create an instance of a class of an iOS app using Frida.

In the past I have successfully done this using a command such as:

```
var instance = ObjC.chooseSync(ObjC.classes.TestClass)[0];
```

However, in this instance, the class that I would like to create an instance of has a `.` in the name so if I try the same command as above I understandably get an error:

```
var instance = ObjC.chooseSync(ObjC.classes.Test.Class)[0];
SyntaxError: expecting field name
```

I had identified the class from the output of:

```
Object.keys(ObjC.classes).filter(function(m){ return m.toLowerCase().includes("test") });
```

The output of this lists a number of classes, all of which are either mangled Swift names, or have a `.` in them so I'm not sure if I simply don't understood a concept here about how Frida handles class names in a Swift and Objective-C app, or there is something I've missed in attempting to create the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjC.classes.TestClass` is just a shorthand in JavaScript for
`ObjC.classes['TestClass']`.

Therefore you should be able to access an `Test.Class` instance this way:

```
var instance = ObjC.chooseSync(ObjC.classes['Test.Class'])[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.  I had been overthinking things and annoyingly had tried something similar to your solution but with additional `()` enclosing the `[]`.